# How to create main menu in offcanvas position with plus signs to expand for their submenus?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, helix3, submenu

I have developed my website, and my main menu works perfectly well; and my main menu also displays well in the offcanvas position if a smartphone or a smaller screen is used. All is good, except for the plus signs not showing up for menu tabs which have sub menus.

More precisely, the submenus of the dropdown menu in the main manu directly show up below the correct menu tab in the offcanvas. I however want that any dropdown menu which exists in the main menu can be extended in the respective offcanvas menutab with a plus button to the right, to see the next level of submenus of the respective menu tab. Is that clear ?

Template : Helix Utlimate

Concretely; that's what I have:

[image]

And that's what I want to have (image of another menu yes, but with the plus signs, and thus the possibility to extend the offcanvas menu):

[image]

UPDATE : I actually figured out that it automatically works if the menu is configured as a normal dropdown menu; but that it doesn't work if the dropdown menu (using the same hierarchization with URL and "#") is defined as a mega menu from the template. So, to be able to use a mega menu in full screen mode, and a dropdown menu with plus expansions in the offcanvas position; do I need to create two main menus ??

Got it, I actually just forgot to switch the Main Menu Module Layout to an option of the helix ultimate template when I switched to it; now it's all settled and working.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to include some screenshots and scribble on them to express your desired adjustment?

Comment: So menu-toggler span tag within the menu adds these. Can you right click and inspect the mobile offcanvas menu and provide a screenshot of the markup ? or provide a link?

Comment: @tonypartridge do you may know what in the css file (I guess the default.css or the template.css?) needs to be modified for it? All I can change are background, text and hover colours, as well the closing symbol of the offcanvas, yet I can't find anything in the css files indicating the plus signs for dropdown extensions... and I'm afraid I can't provide you with the link atm, and didn't understand what you want me to do, could you may re-explain? sry bout that

Comment: Providing font-awesome is loaded it should work, see the demo site spec:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfy3sdysq4ifhdj/Screenshot%202019-07-25%2023.52.45.png?dl=0

So id make sure font-awesome has been added first.

Comment: @tonypartridge could you be more concrete plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I actually just forgot to switch the Main Menu Module Layout to an option of the helix ultimate template when I switched to it; now it's all settled and working.

Comment: Please mark this page as resolved by awarding your answer the big green tick.  This will prevent the automated bumping of this page.